# How to create multiple domain objects from a GSP page

Tags: grails

I have a `Person` class with two properties: `name` and `address`. I want to build a GSP page which allows for 10 users to be created at one time. This is how I'm implementing it and was wondering if there is a better way:

First, make 20 text boxes in the GSP page - 10 with `someperson.name` and 10 with `someperson.address` field names (make these in a loop or code them all individually, doesn't matter).

Second, process the submitted data in the controller. The `someperson` object has the submitted data, but in a not-so-nice structure (`[name: ['Bob', 'John'], address: ['Address 1', 'Address 2']]`), so I call `transpose()` on this to be able to access `name`, `address` pairs.

Then, build a list of `Person` objects using the pairs obtained from the previous step and validate/save them.

Finally, if validation fails (`name` cannot be `null`) then do something... don't know what yet! I'm thinking of passing the collection of `Person` objects to the GSP where they are iterated using a loop and if `hasErrors` then show them... Don't know how to highlight the fields which failed validation...

So, is there a better way (I should probably ask WHAT IS the better way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Grails' data-binding support by declaring a command object like this

```
class PersonCommand {

  List<Person> people = []
}
```

If you construct your form so that the request parameters are named like this:

```
person[0].name=bob
person[0].address=england
person[1].name=john
person[1].address=ireland
```

The data will be automatically bound to the `personCommand` argument of this controller action

```
class MyController {

  def savePeople = {PersonCommand personCommand->

  }
}
```

If you call `personCommand.validate()` it might in turn call `validate()` on each `Person` in `people` (I'm not sure). If it doesn't you can do this yourself by calling

```
boolean allPersonsValid = personCommand.people.every {it.validate()}
```

At this point you'll know whether all `Person` instances are valid. If they are not, you should pass the `PersonCommand` back to the GSP and you can use the Grails tags:

- `<g:eachError>`
- `<g:hasErrors>`
- `<g:renderErrors>`

to highlight the fields in errors. If you're not exactly sure how to use these tags to do the highlight, I suggest you run `grails generate-all` for a domain class and look at the GSP code it generates.

Comment: How does Grails know to bind `person` from the request to the command object? I'd expect the parameters to be required as `people[0].name=bob`

Comment: I keep getting `Error occurred creating command object.` and `Exception Message: Index: 1, Size: 0` with this code http://pastie.org/2951846 Any idea why?

Comment: have a look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677623/grails-command-object-data-binding