# grails 2.1.1 command object service injection for custom validator

Tags: grails, customvalidator, command-objects

Grails 2.1.1

I can't seem to get a command object to be injected with a service so that I can use custom validator. I've tried several things, including 
[Grails command object data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677623/grails-command-object-data-binding) and 
what the 2.1.1 docs on custom validator suggest, I just can't figure this one out..

Relevant Code:

```
class RegistrationCommand {

    String username

    def registrationService
    static constraints = {

        username validator: { val, obj ->
            obj.registrationService.isUsernameUnique(val) }
    }
}

class RegistrationService {

    def isUsernameUnique(username){
        def user = new User(username:username)
        user.validate()
        if(user.errors.hasFieldErrors("username")){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: A nearly identical case works fine for me under 2.1.1. In my case, including the obj second argument and using it was the key, but you already have that.

Comment: Yes, I have @grails.validation.Validateable.. and the error I get is NullPointerException (Cannot invoke method isUsernameUnique() on null object) .

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved.. Issue was due to plugin.**
I'm using a plugin for client side jquery validation (jquery-validation-ui-1.4.2). The command object being created by the plugin's controller wasn't getting injected with the service. The issue was reported https://github.com/limcheekin/jquery-validation-ui/issues/17 . The fix does work but has not been pushed upstream yet.